# NSFont not working properly in macOS Catalina

Tags: ios, macos, macos-catalina, nsfont, nsfontmanager

```
NSFont *fontRef = [NSFont fontWithName:@".SFNS-Light" size:20];
```

Above line of code used to work just fine but now it is not working in Catalina. I am getting nil for fontRef. `.SFNS-Light` stills show as available Fonts. Interesting enough it is still working for

```
[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:size];
```

Anyone experience this issue? What is the best way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code was always wrong. It is illegal and unsupported to specify by name a font whose name begins with a dot, like your `fontWithName:@".SFNS-Light"`. If the goal is to use the system font, ask for the system font.